# implementing AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

How do i implement this using asynctask. i have tried lots of ways that wont work. for now im just reducing the build version to allow network operations on the main thread.
what i want to do is retrieve data from a php script that ive hosted and populate the listview. Some help would be highly appreciated :D

```
public class Database extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url="http://www.mahuwa.com/api/phpserv.php";
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();


    try{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //response to inputstream  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               b.add(json_data.getString("Organization"));

                                  }


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b));


        }

        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Database extends ListActivity {

String url = "http://www.mahuwa.com/api/phpserv.php";
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(/* Your layout */);
    new DatabaseThread().execute();
}

class DatabaseThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        parseJson();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Database.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, b));

    }
}

private void parseJson() {
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    // response to inputstream
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"));

        sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    // to string
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            b.add(json_data.getString("Organization"));

        }

    }

    catch (JSONException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your oncreate method , Here rssFeed is the url you are passing.

```
MyTask().execute(rssFeed);
```

and make a new class called MyTask which extends asynctask.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Utils.getJSONString(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
            showToast("No data found from web!!!");
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        } else {

            try {  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
           json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

           b.add(json_data.getString("Organization"));

                              }


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b));


    }

    catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

and make a new class called Utils and do the Http stuff over there.

```
public class Utils {
public static String getJSONString(String url) {
    String jsonString = null;
    HttpURLConnection linkConnection = null;
    try {
        URL linkurl = new URL(url);
        linkConnection = (HttpURLConnection) linkurl.openConnection();
        int responseCode = linkConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream linkinStream = linkConnection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int j = 0;
            while ((j = linkinStream.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(j);
            }
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            jsonString = new String(data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (linkConnection != null) {
            linkConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException, to resolve it there are 2 possible solutions:

=> **Lazy solution** as below:

> StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
>   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
>   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

=> **Standard solution**: Implement AsyncTask

### Steps/tips are as below:

- Straight way include Network and long running call inside AsyncTask, and then execute that AsyncTask inside `onCreate()` method.
- FYI, you can't update UI from `doInBackground()` method directly, yes if you want to update UI while doing from `doInBackground()` any how then implement `runOnUiThread()`

  OR

  Update UI from `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public class Database extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String url="http://www.mahuwa.com/api/phpserv.php";
    new ConnectToServer(this, url, getListView());
}
    class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        Context context;
        String url;
        ListView lv;
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

        ConnectToServer(Context context, String url, ListView lv) {
            this.context = context;
            this.url = url;
            this.lv = lv;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // UI work allowed here
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Database.this);
            // setup dialog here
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String returnVal) {
            Sync s = new Sync(Database.this);
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(returnVal);
                JSONObject json_data=null;
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                {
                   json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   b.add(json_data.getString("Organization"));

                                      }


            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b));


            }

            catch(JSONException e1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
            return;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strReq) {
            String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



            try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

            //response to inputstream  
            try
            {
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

              sb = new StringBuilder();

              String line = null;

              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
              {
                 sb.append(line + "\n");
              }

              is.close();

              result = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      String url="http://www.mahuwa.com/api/phpserv.php";
      String result = null;
      InputStream is = null;
      StringBuilder sb = null; 
      ProgressDialog pd; 
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     pd = new ProgressDialog(DataBase.this,"Wait..");     
     new TheTask().execute();
```

Asynctask class as ainner class of your activity class

```
   class TheTask ends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List> {

 protected void onPreExecute()
 {
     pd.show();
 } 
@Override
protected List doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
       ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();


        try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
             sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            b.add(json_data.getString("Organization"));
         }      
         }
         catch(Exception e){
              e.printStacktrace();
            } 

    return b;
}
protected void onPostExecute(List b)
{
    pd.dismiss();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> Database.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b));
}
   }
```

For more information check the link below especially the topic under the heading The 4 steps

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

onPreExecute invoked on ui thread. Show progress dialog

doInBackground(param) invoked on the background thread. do not update ui here

onPostExecute(param) The result of doInBackground() computation is parameter to onPostExecute(). dismiss progress dialog and update ui here.